# Get Items with some date column less than 3 days ago in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am working in Azure Logic App to get items from a SharePoint list created less then 3 days ago.

I wanted to initialize a date variable but there isn't date type in Logic app.

Anyone has an idea how to create X for a filter:

"Created lt X" where X is 3 days ago?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the flow/design screenshots which you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example and be aware, there is no such thing as a date variable, they're all just treated as strings ...

[image: Get Item]

Expression = `formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -3), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ')`

Be aware, I used `gt` (greater than) but you can use `ge` (greater than or equal to), `eq` (equal to), `le` (less than or equal to) or any of the other supported comparison operators.

Answer (score 0):

X = string(addDays(utcNow(),-3))